# foundation 6 data equalizer

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 6 plugin data equalizer to make two columns in a row the same height, I have got this working although, I am including an image as a separator between the different sections on the web page. as the web page gets smaller, the two columns increase in size and overlap the separator image, is there anyway to prevent this.

```
 <section class="about-us-gallery" data-equalizer="about">
  <div class="medium-6 columns empty bluebg" data-equalizer-watch="about" ></div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns empty"data-equalizer-watch="about" ></div>


  <div class="content-about-us" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-6 columns "data-equalizer-watch="about">
          <h2 class="white">heading</h2>
<p class="white">dkdkdkdkdkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</p>
        </div>

        <div class="medium-6 columns"data-equalizer-watch="about">
          <h2>heading</h2>
<p>talkdjf;alkdjf;alkdj;alkdjflasdjf;asdkfja;sldkjf;alsdkfj;asldkfjlasdjf </p>
        </div>


     </div>
   </div>
</section>

<!-- Seperater image -->
<div class="separator-image bar-image"></div>
```

Comment: Is the image a background image? Equalise has a number of issues with images, particularly if lazy-loading. You can execute `Foundation.reint('equalizer')` when the DOM has loaded to get it to re-check the image sizes and change accordingly, but you need to make sure that also executes on resize / rotation. See the JS plugin section of Foundations Docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#adding-plugins-after-page-load

Comment: How / where do I place the Foundation.reint('equalizer')?  I'm having a similar issue with embedded video.  The equalization isn't working because the video loads after the page loads so the heights are off.

Answer (score 1):

Might need to see an example to help you more. I set up a demo you can form and link back here: http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/ENbKxd

Also it looks like you have 2 columns that are not in a row which may be causing issues

```
<div class="medium-6 columns empty bluebg" data-equalizer-watch="about" ></div>
```